# Hide Load more button on filter tabs except for All (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I have a filterable tabs and photos by categories. The first category is All, and 4 more categories.
I have two functions:

1. Is for filtering:

   ```
        $(function() {
        $(".filter_portfolio li").on('click', function() {
        let category = $(this).attr("data-filter");
        $(".filter_portfolio li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        let item = $(".portfolio .portfolio_item");
        item.fadeOut("slow");
        item.each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass(category)) {
        $(this).fadeIn(1000);
        }
        });
        });
        });
   ```
2. Is for Load more button loading 12 more photos

   ```
        $(function (){
        const elements = $(".portfolio_item.invisible");
        $(".portfolio_item ").slice(0, 12).show();
        if ($(elements).length !== 0) {
            $(".load_btn").show();
        }
        $(".load_btn").on('click', function() {
        $('.portfolio_item.invisible:hidden').slice(0, 12).slideDown( "slow" );
        if ($(".portfolio_item.invisible:hidden").length === 0) {
        $(".load_btn").fadeOut("slow");}
        });
        });
   ```

The problem is that I can't manage to show this .load_btn in All category, but not to show in all other categories.

I tried to add this code to the first function

```
if (!$(".filter_cat", ".active").hasClass('loadbtn')) {
    $(".load_btn").hide();
} else {
    $(".load_btn").show();
}
```

**First function with the if else statement **

```
        $(function() {
        $(".filter_portfolio li").on('click', function() {
        let category = $(this).attr("data-filter");
        $(".filter_portfolio li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        let item = $(".portfolio .portfolio_item");
        item.fadeOut("slow");
        item.each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass(category)) {
        $(this).fadeIn(1000);
        }
        if (!$(".filter_cat", ".active").hasClass('loadbtn')) {
        $(".load_btn").hide();
        } else {
        $(".load_btn").show();
        }
        });
        });
        });
```

But when I click on other tabs, then go back to the All tab, the loadmore button is not there.

This is the HTML:

```js
//Filter
$(function() {
    $(".filter_portfolio li").on('click', function() {
        let category = $(this).attr("data-filter");
        $(".filter_portfolio li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        if ($(this).hasClass('loadbtn')) {
            $(".load_btn").show();
        } else {
            $(".load_btn").hide();
        }
        let item = $(".portfolio .portfolio_item");
       item.fadeOut("slow");
        item.each(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass(category)) {
                $(this).fadeIn(1000);
            }

        });
    });

});
//Load more 12 + 12
$(function (){
        const elements = $(".portfolio_item.invisible");
        $(".portfolio_item").slice(0, 12).show();
        if ($(elements).length !== 0) {
            $(".load_btn").show();
        }
        $(".load_btn").on('click', function() {
        $('.portfolio_item.invisible:hidden').slice(0, 12).slideDown( "slow" );
        if ($(".portfolio_item.invisible:hidden").length === 0) {
        $(".load_btn").fadeOut("slow");}
       
    });
    });
```

```css
.portfolio_item {
display: block;
}

.portfolio_item.invisible {
    display: none;
}


.filter_portfolio {
    display: flex;
    margin: 93px auto 69px;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 65%;
    align-items: center;
list-style: none;
}

.filter_cat {
    padding: 13px 15px;
    color: #717171;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 42px;
    flex-basis: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-top: 1px solid #DADADA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DADADA;
}

.filter_cat:nth-child(odd) {
    border-right: 1px solid #DADADA;
    border-left: 1px solid #DADADA;
}

.filter_cat.active {
    border: 2px solid #18CFAB;
    color: #18CFAB;
}

.portfolio {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.load {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 70px;
}

.load_btn {
    padding: 22px 17px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 170px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: #18CFAB;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    justify-content: space-around;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="filter_portfolio">
                    <li class="filter_cat active loadbtn" data-filter="all">All</li>
                    <li class="filter_cat" data-filter="tab1">Tab1</li>
                    <li class="filter_cat" data-filter="tab2">Tab2</li>
                    <li class="filter_cat" data-filter="tab3">Tab3</li>
                    <li class="filter_cat" data-filter="tab4">Tab4</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="portfolio">
                <div class="portfolio_item all tab1">
                Tab1
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio_item all tab2">
                Tab2
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio_item all tab3">
                Tab3
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio_item all tab4">
                Tab4
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio_item invisible all tab1">Tab1.1</div>
                 <div class="portfolio_item invisible all tab2">Tab2.1</div>
                  <div class="portfolio_item invisible all tab3">Tab3.1</div>
                   <div class="portfolio_item invisible all tab4">Tab4.1</div></div>
                   <div class="load"><button class="load_btn"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Load more</button></div>
```

Comment: _“I tried to add this code to the first function”_ - please show stuff like this _in context_, otherwise we have no way of telling _where_ you actually added it.

Comment: You just added the `active` class using `$(this).addClass("active")`, so there should be no need to go _looking for_ which element has that class now - it’s `$(this)`. So you should be able to simply check `$(this).hasClass('loadbtn')` now.

Comment: When I add the if ($(this).hasClass('loadbtn')) {
                $(".load_btn").show();
            } else {
                $(".load_btn").hide();
            }
Then when I go back to All, it appears there, but all hidden photos that should appear by clicking on button, appear automtically in All

Comment: Please provide a _proper_ [mre] of what you are doing. For example the `.portfolio_item.invisible` elements you are trying to select, can’t be found anywhere in the HTML you have shown so far - so how are we supposed to be able to tell what is actually going on?

Comment: I added code snippet, but in this environment the hidden items are shown when I run the Code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the reason.
From the portfolio_item invisible items - remove all class by default.
And add this class only when the click is triggered on the Load more button.